# Swift iOS -How can I pass a value Obtained Directly from a within TableViewCell's SubClass to the TableView's didSelectRow?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexpath

Before anyone suggests to pull the Firebase data from within the PlayerController's viewWillAppear, I already know how to do that and if I did it that way I know how to pass the data to the ScoreController. In this situation I need to pull the data directly from within the cell and somehow pass the data back from there.

I have a tableView inside a PlayerController that displays the randomPower, name, and score of each player. Inside the tableView's cell I pull the name and score from Firebase using a function `getScoreDataFromFirebase()`. The function is located directly inside the tableView's PlayerCell and once I get the values from Firebase I initialize the cell's name and score outlets right then and there.

Inside the tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath I call `cell.getScoreDataFromFirebase()` and everything works fine because both outlets display the correct values.

From that point on I have a ScoreController. When a tableView cell is chosen the score is sent to the ScoreController.

The problem is since I'm pulling the data **directly from within the cell itself** the only way I could pass the score (pulled from Firebase) to ScoreController was to 1st set a `didSet` score property inside the cell.

Still inside the cell when I pull the score data from Firebase 2nd I initialize the score property with it

3rd inside the tableView's cellForAtIndexPath I use an `if let` to pass the value from the cell's score property to the the tableData.

When I first try to send the indexPath of that tableData over to the ScoreController sometimes it's nil even though the cell's score property definitely has a value (I used to break points to check). If I select any of the very first few tableView cells that are visible they will have a nil value for the score property. However if I scroll further down through the cells and back up then those same cells will no longer have a nil score property.

What I found out was the `if let` statement was running before the Firebase code was pulled so the score property was nil for first few cells that are on scene. The odd thing is everything works fine once I start scrolling.

**How can I pass a value pulled directly from a cell to the tableView's didSelectRow?**

PlayerModel:

```
class PlayerModel{
   name:String?
   score:String?
   randomPower:String?
}
```

TableViewCell SubClass:

```
class PlayerCell:UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var randomPowerLabel: UILabel!

    internal var score: String?{
        didSet{
            print("**********\(score ?? "*********")")
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
         super.prepareForReuse()
         nameLabel.text = " "
         scoreLabel.text = " "
    }

    func getScoreDataFromFirebase(){

         let scoreRef = usersRef?.child("score")

         scoreRef?.observe( .value, with: {
              (snapshot) in

              for child in snapshot.children{

                  let user = child as! DataSnapshot

                      for player in user.children{

                           let eachPlayer = player as! DataSnapshot

                           if let dict = eachPlayer.value as? [String:Any]{

                                 let name = dict["name"] as? String ?? " "
                                 let score = dict["score"] as? String ?? " "

                                 self.nameLabel.text = name
                                 self.scoreLabel.text = score

                                 self.score = score
                           }
                      }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

TableView:

```
class PlayerController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak fileprivate var tableView: UITableView!

var players = [PlayerModel]() // this array is populated with data from a previous vc. The number of players in the array are the same exact number of players that's pulled from the getScoreDataFromFirebase() function

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return players.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as! PlayerCell

     let cellData = players[indexPath.row]     

     cellData.randomPowerLabel.text = cellData.power

     cell.getScoreDataFromFirebase()

     if let score = cell.score{
        cellData.score = score
     }

     return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }

    let scoreVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScoreController") as! ScoreController

    scoreVC.score = players[indexPath.row].score

}
```

Comment: you move the data of specific row to next VC

Comment: @KhawarIslam moving the data to the next vc isn't the problem. I do that in the didSelectRow scoreVC.score = players[indexPath.row].score. The problem is I need to set the players[indexPath.row].score from the score pulled from the cell getScoreDataFromFirebase() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using **delegation** :
Create a **protocol**

```
protocol UpdateValueDelegate: class {
    func changeValue(score: String, row: Int)
}
```

Your `UIViewController` should look like this :

```
PlayController : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UpdateValueDelegate  
{
       var scoreDict:[String:String] = [:]
        //
       //  

      func changeValue(score: String, row: Int)
      {
            self.scoreDict["\(row)"] = score
      }
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set **cell.delegate = self** and **cell.row = indexPath.row**

Your `UITableViewCell` should look like this :

```
class PlayerCell:UITableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    weak  var delegate: UpdateValueDelegate?
    var row: Int?
    //
    //
}
```

Finally pass score from **getScoreDataFromFirebase** by calling delegate function:

```
func getScoreDataFromFirebase()
{
    //
    //
    delegate. changeValue(score: localScore, row: self.row)
}
```

Now you have the value in your viewController from where it can be easily passed to `didSelectRow` using the global dictionary ** scoreDict**.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    var score = self.scoreDict["\(indexPath.row)"]
   // Use score
}
```

Comment: thanks i'll try it in a few. I didn't try  a delegate method because I was worried the wrong data would get passed to the cells. Gimme a few

Comment: Sure. Another thing. I have taken row variable above. You should probably take an array of integers since getScoreDataFromFirebase is called for each cell. So to keep track of cell row, you need to set this in an array.

Comment: Hmmm I never thought of that, it's actually new to me but it makes sense because it tracks everything. I have to digest it. Thanks. Once i try the code I'll get back to you if there's a problem but if its good I'll choose it as the answer.

Comment: Edited my answer. I have demonstrated use of collection for storing row and score and passing that along.

Comment: I'm sure you forgot but delegate are supposed to be be declared using weak> weak var delegate: UpdateValueDelegate?

Comment: My mistake. You can do that. I hope that won't be of much trouble. I have updated that in the above code as well.

Comment: I know how to use delegates, I just wanted you to update your answer for the next person who comes along. Your going to have to declare  the delegate as a class to use weak>> protocol UpdateValueDelegate: class{ ...}

Comment: Sure thing.. :)

Comment: Worked like Charm! I like the way you used the scoreDict to keep track of the row data and accompanying scoreValue. Very nice indeed :) Thanks!!!