# How to pass data UItableViewCell to Another viewController and UItableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I need help.I'm working with swift 4 and firebase. I am trying to pass data to one viewController to another viewController.So, my question is, how can i pass data from one tableView to another viewController and one UITableViewCell. Need help to solve this issue

Comment: Use delegation to pass data from cell to controller.

Comment: i do it but  didn't pass data uitableview to uitableview .

Comment: if you  get data from api than just pass product id to view controller

Comment: @BiswajitBanik how you get data from api or coredata?

Comment: Give me solution code in didselectrowindex method?

Comment: @BiswajitBanik : You should focus on the principle rather than the solution.
Whenever you have to pass data from one class to another, you follow different approaches. I won't name them all, but as per your case, delegation is the right way to go ahead.Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773528/swift-ios-how-can-i-pass-a-value-obtained-directly-from-a-within-tableviewcell/48773814#48773814

Comment: just pass your product object to destination controller (injection)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "YourSegueName") {
        //get a reference to the destination view controller
        let destinationVC:ViewControllerClass = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerClass

        //set properties on the destination view controller
        destinationVC.propertyName = dataYouWantToPass
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
//can take this optional as well
var selectedIndex = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchViewtoVC", sender: self)}
}
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  if let yourVC = segue.destinationViewController as? YourViewController {
     if let details = productDetails {
        let singleProd = details[selectedIndex]
        yourVC.singleProd = singleProd

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get the cell  which is selected by you. By calling the function "cellForRowAtIndexPath" on tableView in "didSelectRowAt" function you can get the cell.After that when you got the cell  you can easily get data from cell and set the properties or we pass the data in the other controller.This was the solution if you have to pass data on "didSelectRowAt" TableViewdelegate. 
But if you want to pass data on button tap in cell or want to get text from textField/TextView when ever user is entering data, then you have to make custom delegates in cell so that they can tell if any action is performed

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way to pass data. You can also pass data using delegate approach.

**First View Controller**

Here you are pass data based on user select `UITableviewCell`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchViewtoVC", sender: self.productDetails?[indexPath.row])
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         if segue.identifier == "searchViewtoVC" {
                guard let data = self.sender as? Product else {
                    return
                }
               let goNext = segue.destination as! SeconViewViewController
               goNext.product = data
          }   
    }
```

**Second View Controller**

Second view controller you want to receive data based on select Product from first view controller

```
var product:Product?

override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       print(product ?? "")

 }
```